# How does one maintain memory with the putenv system call?

Tags: c++, unix, system-calls

The POSIX system call `putenv` states that the allocated memory string cannot be freed by the caller after the call to `putenv`. Therefore, you cannot call `putenv` with an automatic variable.

Example:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    char envVar[] = "MYVAR=Value";
    // putenv(envVar); //ERROR!
    char *memory = static_cast<char*>(std::malloc(sizeof(envVar)));
    std::strcpy(memory, envVar);
    putenv(memory); //OK!
}
```

My question at this point is ... how is the environment variable memory `free`'d? Does one need to maintain their on separate storage and constantly remove things from the environment? I.e.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <map>

static std::map<std::string, char*> environmentBlock;

static struct EnvironmentBlockFreer
{
    ~EnvironmentBlockFreer()
    {
        for(std::map<std::string, char*>::iterator it = environmentBlock.begin()
            it != environmentBlock.end(); ++it)
        {
            putenv(it->first.c_str()); //Remove entry from the environment
            std::free(static_cast<void *>(it->second)); //Nuke the memory
        }
    }
} EnvironmentBlockFreer_ENTRY;

int main()
{
    char envVar[] = "MYVAR=Value";
    char *memory = static_cast<char*>(std::malloc(sizeof(envVar)));
    std::strcpy(memory, envVar);
    putenv(memory); //OK!
    environmentBlock.insert(std::pair<std::string, char*>(
        "MYVAR", memory)); //Remember the values for later!
}
```

EDIT: It does look like I need to track this myself, at least according to Valgrind:

```
/* This program: */

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
        char str[] = "MYVAR=Example";
        char *mem = malloc(sizeof(str));
        strcpy(mem, str);
        putenv(mem);
}

/* Produced output:

==4219== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==4219== Copyright (C) 2002-2010, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==4219== Using Valgrind-3.6.0.SVN-Debian and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==4219== Command: ./a.out
==4219== 
==4219== 
==4219== HEAP SUMMARY:
==4219==     in use at exit: 14 bytes in 1 blocks
==4219==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 1 frees, 194 bytes allocated
==4219== 
==4219== LEAK SUMMARY:
==4219==    definitely lost: 14 bytes in 1 blocks
==4219==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4219==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4219==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4219==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4219== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==4219== 
==4219== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==4219== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 13 from 8)
*/
```

Comment: I wouldn't bother with malloc/free, store strings in your map and pass their c_str to putenv. As long as you don't need the absurd feature of putenv that you can modify the environment by writing to the string, that is...

Comment: @Steve -- these were just garbage tests I threw together in 5 mins.. not real code :) Didn't want to cause problems if `putenv` actually called `free` on the memory block so I used `malloc`.

Comment: In that case I'd say, "yes, but for heaven's sake do it by surrounding putenv with a nicer C++ interface that copies user-supplied strings".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Don't use [`putenv()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/putenv.html) if you are worried about the memory leaking.

That's why POSIX provides [`setenv()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setenv.html) and [`unsetenv()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/unsetenv.html) as well - those take control of the memory and manage it.

---

Quoting the `putenv()` manual page (URL above):

> The `putenv()` function shall use the *string* argument to set environment variable values. The *string* argument should point to a string of the form "`name= value`". The `putenv()` function shall make the value of the environment variable *name* equal to *value* by altering an existing variable or creating a new one. In either case, the string pointed to by *string* shall become part of the environment, so altering the string shall change the environment. The space used by *string* is no longer used once a new string which defines *name* is passed to `putenv()`.

Answer (score 2):

No, you don't need to do that manually. Memory for your environment is freed by the OS (as part of your process memory) when your process exits.

Comment: What about when an environment variable is overwritten?

Comment: I guess that if either you make a *lot* of changes to the environment, or else you're using a leak detector and want to eliminate false positives; then just leaking the memory to be cleaned up by the OS is unacceptable. In principle there's nothing special here about the environment, you could just as well say that any memory can be leaked, especially if it's an O(1) quantity of memory.